# Fix plugin version and sync project Error In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently opening this file Android Studio 2.1 and the the app is created in Android Studio version 1.5.

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "abf87974ef3c08e3258fe37c7d5001161385f549"
Fix plugin version and sync project
Open File
```

I have problem during importing Android Project and it shows error.
After pressing "Fix Plugin" it shows me "Failed To Update".

This is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.asharbhutta.com.challanlogin"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4'
}
```

This is gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Oct 21 11:34:03 PDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-bin.zip
```

Comment: Your Gradle plugin is too old? Please show the `build.gradle` files.

Comment: yes i know please tell me how to fix it..

Comment: @cricket_007 now you can see my gradle file ..

Comment: Thanks! Now, there should be two of them... One in the root of the project and the other in the `app/` directory. If that is not the case, then how did you generate this project?

Comment: i have already mentioned that i have imported this app..

Comment: Imported from where? Can you provide a link to that? I am using the same versions of Gradle you have shown, and I do not get an error

Comment: i have taken this project from my friend, and he is using 1.5 android studio..

Comment: Your friend might want to learn about version control, if not already using. It would help if we could clone the project and try to reproduce the error. As I said in the answer, though, that plugin version shouldn't even work.

Comment: than please tell me how can i see the code, i can't seen layout files and java files.. :(

Comment: I don't have your code. I don't really think I need to say how to use Android Studio, either. If you can't expand the `app/` directory there and see the files, then your friend didn't send you the project correctly.

Comment: i can give you access on that folder which is on google drive from where you can see this Project files.. Can you do me a favor.. because i have to submit my code tomorrow.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to find `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4'` in [**Jcenter / Bintray**](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view).

Therefore, this error makes sense

> Fix plugin version and sync project

As of this post, the latest stable version is `2.1.2`

Note: Gradle is completely separate from the Android plugin. The version of `gradle-2.14-bin` does not always match the plugin number.

---

This should all be self-explanatory, but to clarify, this is the corrected `build.gradle`.

#### Project `/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

#### `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.asharbhutta.com.challanlogin"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4' // This shouldn't be here
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i read the code... because i need this project code..

Comment: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4` -- Change this `2.1.4` to a number value that you can find from BinTray

Comment: Click the "Bintray" link in my answer. Bintray is a website. Not part of Android Studio.

Comment: Than,,..? who can i see the number that you are telling me..?

Comment: @MusaJutt I'm sorry that you are having difficulties, but I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: I can't see your project without a link to anything, and yes, I did change it. See the comment in the code?

Comment: what if i can give you access to my laptop via TeamViewer..?

Comment: I won't use TeamViewer, sorry. I've given way more information than necessary to fix the problem. If all else fails, File > New > Project. Don't touch any Gradle settings. Move your Java code and XML files into that project.

Answer (score 0):

In Build.gradel
in Dependencies classpath end with + sign like i shown

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**2.2.0+**'