# IntelliJ Idea Android project: Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

**EDIT:**

The solution prompted by @Percy Vega on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536013/intellij-build-error-context-missmatch) post worked for me.

Running **idea64.exe** instead of **idea.exe** when you have a 64 bit JRE seems to do the trick.

---

I've never used Gradle, so I'm pretty confused right now:
I've been trying for a while now to get this to work, but without any success.
I'm trying to create an Android project in **IntelliJ Idea 2016.3.2**, but as soon as I create it, I get **this message:**

[image]

On the message log:

```
Gradle sync started

Gradle sync failed: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\xico\.gradle\daemon,pid=5660,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
        Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=08e53ecc-a9ee-405c-afc9-a7ba8779d6ee,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\xico\.gradle\daemon,pid=2336,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

---

I've downloaded Gradle 3.3 and stored it at:

```
C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-3.3
```

Here are the Gradle setting, inside of IntelliJ. Iv'e also tried to check 'Offline Work', but it gives the same result:

[image]

The project root's **build.gradle** file:

[image]

And the **app´s build.gradle** file:

[image]

How can I manage to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

*PS: If any more information would be useful please just ask.*

Comment: You don't need to install Gradle yourself. Most Android projects are configured with a "Gradle wrapper"

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536013/intellij-build-error-context-missmatch

Comment: Also, please do not use images. Actually paste your code into the question.

Comment: @Charuka hey, thank you so much, apparently the fix for me was to run **idea64.exe** instead of **idea.exe**, since I had a 64 bit JRE installed.

Comment: @cricket_007 alright, my bad!

Comment: @Frank  aww glad you fixed it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One specifies the version of Gradle inside a `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, whose contents look like this:

```
#Thu Oct 06 00:21:08 IDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Assuming your project structure is:

```
my-project
 |- app
     |+ libs
     |+ src
 |- gradle
     |- wrapper
         |- gradle-wrapper.properties  << here
```

Then, AS downloads it and typically installs it (on a Windows machine) to:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-<version>-all
```

Comment: OP isn't using the wrapper, btw

Comment: @cricket_007 That's true. Notwithstanding, OP also mentioned they never used Gradle before... It's worth mentioning this option exists because it simplifies working with Gradle somewhat... (just like you commented on the question).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your error `Java home is different`. That is some configuration issue you have within the OS / Application, not really Android, Gradle related.

---

Anyways,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

This line does not correspond directly to the Gradle version. That is the Android Gradle build library. As of this post, `3.3.0` [is not a valid version](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view).

Also worth mentioning, that while the Android documentation states Gradle 2.14.1 and higher will work, careful that there could potentially be some breaking changes at some point.

---

Some other posts I've answered regarding this type of Gradle problem

[What is the difference between an app dependency and a module dependency/plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910129)

[Fix plugin version and sync project Error In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747841)

Comment: It's solved now (edit), but still thanks! I found the Java Home problem quite strange, though, as I had never had any problem with android + java on intelliJ before.

Comment: @Frank don't answer by editing the question. If you found a solution please post an answer describing what worked for you.

Comment: @Dev-iL The link in the second comment has a solution that worked

Comment: @cricket_007 Noticed. Then this warrants a close-as-duplicate...